# No route matches? Should be simple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep running into an error that is becoming quite frustrating - I have a Mail setup that sends out an activation e-mail to new users.

I keep getting the error: `no route matches {:controller => "activations", :action => "create"}`

Here's the code:

```
# routes. I tried all of these individually.
match 'activations/create'
match 'activations/create/:activation_code' => 'activations#create', :as => :activate
match 'activate/:activation_code' => 'activations#create', :as => :activate

# controller. This is the line that refers to UserMailer, that then causes the error.
UserMailer.activation_instructions(@user).deliver

# UserMailer.rb
def activation_instructions(user)
  @user = user
  @account_activation_url = activate_url(user.perishable_token) # error raised here
  mail(:to => "#{user.login} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered" )
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Standard reply for routing questions: what does `rake routes` say? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
match 'activations/create(/:activation_code)' => 'activations#create', :as => :activate
```